# use grep to return all lines from the first line matching the pattern to a different pattern

Tags: grep

i believe i need to use grep because i am searching multiple files and i need for the file name to appear as a header on each line. i am using terminal on macOS.

so say i have one file, file1, in directory 'dir' with the following contents:

```
>species one; trnF(ggc)
GGCCC
AACGC
>species one; rrnS
TAGCA
GGCAC
```

and an additional file, file2, in directory 'dir' with the following contents

```
>species two; trnF(gga)
GGACG
CGACG
GCAC
>species two; rrnS
GCATG
GGCAG
```

i'd like to get the following output:

```
dir/file1:>species one; trnF(ggc)
dir/file1-GGCCC
dir/file1-AACGC
--
dir/file2:>species two; trnF(gga)
dir/file2-GGACG
dir/file2-CGACG
dir/file2-GCAC
```

i can get a certain specified number of lines after the line with the pattern using -A:

```
$ grep -A 2 'trnF' dir/file*
```

but the files have a different number of lines after the grep command so i get the following:

```
dir/file1:>species one; trnF(ggc)
dir/file1-GGCCC
dir/file1-AACGC
--
dir/file2:>species two; trnF(gga)
dir/file2-GGACG
dir/file2-CGACG
```

how can i get all of the contents until the next '>' symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have discovered, `grep -A` is inflexible in that it only allows for specifying  a static number of lines of context.

Instead, here's an `awk` command that detects when the selected sequence occurs, and outputs it until it encounter another sequence header that does not match the criteria:

```
awk -v name='trnF' -v OFS=':\t' '
    FNR == 1 && NR > 1 { print "--" }
    /^>/ { out=0 }
    $0 ~ "^>.*" name { out=1 }
    out == 1 { print FILENAME, $0 }' files
```

The `-v name=something` option will assign `something` to the `name` variable in the `awk` code, and it will be used as part of a regular expression that matches a fasta header line that contains the given string.

The output of the last piece of `awk` may look something like

```
file:   >species one; trnF(ggc)
file:   GGCCC
file:   AACGC
--
file1:  >species one; trnF(ggc)
file1:  GGCCC
file1:  AACGC
--
```

(the `:` followed by a tab used as a delimiter between the filename and the data may be changed by setting `OFS` to something else on the command line with `-v OFS=somethingelse`)

Comment: @LL3 Yes that would work.  The only issue with this (that my original code had as well) is that it'll always print `--` between files regardless of whether there was a match at all, but that's just a matter of keeping track of whether the current file had a match or not (I won't add that code ATM).

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /bin/bash

for i in dir/file*
do
    [ -n "$is_first_file" ] && echo
    awk -v filename="$i" 'BEGIN { temp=1 }  { if ($1 ~ /^>/ && temp == 0){exit} } {if ( $1 ~ /^>/ && temp == 1 ) {print filename,"\b:","\b"$0,temp=0 } else { print filename,"\b-","\b"$0 }}' "$i"
    echo -n '--'
    is_first_file=no
done
echo -n -e "\b\b"
```

Not much experienced with `awk`, but i guess this should give you the exact output you want.

Also one mistake that i do often.
Don’t run this script like `sh script_name`.

It uses `-e` in `echo` which would need `bash`.

Run it either like `./script_name` or `bash script_name`.

Comment: You know you can always use `printf` as a replacement for `echo -e` in `/bin/sh` scripts.